# Radio Button Validation in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have multiple different radio buttons, in different group boxes. Before the user is able to "Save" their form, all fields need to be filled in. So I am trying to make sure all radio buttons are filled in. At the moment I am trying to use the following code:

```
 if (!(this.RoundTrip.Checked || this.OneWay.Checked))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select an option for Trip Type");


                if (!(this.NorthRad.Checked || this.ExpressRad.Checked || this.ExpressRad.Checked))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select an Option for Route Type");

                }
                if (!(this.YesNeeded.Checked || this.NotNeeded.Checked))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select an option for accessibility");

                }
                if (this.AdultNum.Value == 0 && this.SeniorNum.Value == 0 && this.ChildNum.Value == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select at least one ticket");

                }
                return;
            }
```

with this code it is not allowing me to click on the save button, but no message boxes come up. And even after I fill in the radio boxes I cannot click the save button. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems correct but, it will always return at last line.
Maybe what you need is something like this;

```
private void btnSave_Clicked()
    {
        if (!IsValidDataEntered()) return;

        Save();
    }

    private bool IsValidDataEntered()
    {
        if (!(this.RoundTrip.Checked || this.OneWay.Checked))
            MessageBox.Show("Select an option for Trip Type");

        else if (!(this.NorthRad.Checked || this.ExpressRad.Checked || this.ExpressRad.Checked))
            MessageBox.Show("Select an Option for Route Type");

        else if (!(this.YesNeeded.Checked || this.NotNeeded.Checked))
            MessageBox.Show("Select an option for accessibility");

        else if (this.AdultNum.Value == 0 && this.SeniorNum.Value == 0 &&
                 this.ChildNum.Value == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Select at least one ticket");

        else
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is top level `if` condition causing the problem, other conditions will not evaluate as top level condition could be `true` in your testing.

Probably what you need is...

```
if (!(this.RoundTrip.Checked || this.OneWay.Checked))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select an option for Trip Type");
}
else if (!(this.NorthRad.Checked || this.ExpressRad.Checked || this.ExpressRad.Checked))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select an Option for Route Type");

}
else if (!(this.YesNeeded.Checked || this.NotNeeded.Checked))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select an option for accessibility");

}
else if (this.AdultNum.Value == 0 && this.SeniorNum.Value == 0 && this.ChildNum.Value == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select at least one ticket");
}
return;
```

On the other note, since you have `groupbox` for grouping you could use simple `Linq` to evaluate a group.

```
var group1Validation = GroupBox1.Controls
                          .OfType<RadioButton>()
                          .Any(r=>r.Checked); 


var group2Validation = GroupBox2.Controls
                          .OfType<RadioButton>()
                          .Any(r=>r.Checked); 


if(!group1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Select an option for Trip Type");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating that NO selection has been made then you need to be using && not ||.

If no option has been checked you need to verify that neither radio button has been selected. With an OR, if the first logical check satisfies the condition then it won't check the second one. Also in your case, assuming there is no other radio button that says N/A or something, your inner of statements will always be True since at least one radio button won't be checked if another is checked in its place.